# ¿Dónde tiene Django el modelo de la tabla auth_user para poder añadir más columnas?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

Tratando de volcar una tabla de usuario desde Mysql a SQLite, veo que Django tiene una tabla auth_user donde puedo volcar datos, pero necesito añadir más columnas a esa tabla. ¿Dónde tiene Django el modelo de auth_user para añadir más columnas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te refieres al model User. Es parte de un paquete de django. Como es algo muy común te pongo este extracto de Código Facilito https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/django-user-model

Si tenemos la necesidad de agregar nuevos campos y atributos sobre nuestro modelo User, una muy buena idea es generar una relación uno a uno con un nuevo modelo.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
```

En este caso el modelo Profile posee todos aquellos atributos que no cuenta el modelo User, atributos que serán necesarios para nuestra lógica de negocio.

```
user = User.objects.last()
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, bio='sin biografía por el momento')
```

Como la relación es uno a uno, ambos objetos podrán acceder a dicha relación.

```
user.profile.bio
profile.user.username
```

Si queremos agregar funcionalidad, simplemente nos apoyamos de la relación.

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...

```
def say_hello(self):
    return "Hello, my name is {}".format(self.user.first_name)
```